# The concurrent snapshot for publication 'xx' is not available because it has not been fully generated or the Log Reader A

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am having all sorts of trouble getting SQL Server (2005) to work properly. When I run the client (SQL Server Express 2005) I get the following error "The concurrent snapshot for publication 'xx' is not available because it has not been fully generated or the Log Reader A"

The error is cropped off.

I have tried: 
 - Deleting the subscription
 - Deleting the publication and starting again
 - Restarting the server and client.
 - Shrinking the database

All without any change.

I know that the client can see the network share \servername\repldata which has a UNC subfolder with the snapshot in it (a folders deeper with the pubName and dateTime encoding as expected)

Any tips or trips would be REALLY appreciated

Comment: Can you qualify what type of replication you are using, snapshot/transactional/merge? Are you using push or pull subscriptions?

Answer (score 13):

But here is the solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/baf99181-2fe1-4e6b-ba45-5d1d08103550/

1) delete the subscription & the whole publication that is not working

2) run a select on these tables to see if there are still rows for the publication database available:

```
select * from msdb..MSdistpublishers
select * from distribution..MSpublisher_databases
select * from distribution..MSpublications
select * from distribution..MSarticles
select * from distribution..MSsubscriptions
```

3) now delete all rows that have still the 'publisher_db' from the just deleted publisher database:

```
delete from distribution..MSarticles where publisher_db = '<NameOfDatabase>'
delete from distribution..MSsubscriptions where publisher_db = '<NameOfDatabase>'
```

4) re-create the publication & the subscriber as normal

That should do the trick :-)

Comment: No need to apologize for a late answer -- such contributions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. *Has* the snapshot for the publication been generated?  Sometimes this takes a looong time and sometimes it gets deferred to a later time.  If it is made, you should be able to find it on disk somewhere.
2. Make sure that the Log Reader is running on the Publisher, if this is Transactional Replication, which I assume it is.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, it was due to fact that "MSSubscriptions" table on distributor database had nosync_type=1 and status=2. Changed above to 0 and 1 respectively.

Reinitialized the snapshot again and then distributor agent started picking up these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinitialized the snapshot again (new snapshot, don't reuse old one) and then distributor agent started picking up these changes.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just matter of giving the Log-Reader and Distribution service accounts DB_Owner access to the publishing database. I'm not sure if they were both required, but it was an easy fix.